# How to change custom cell image and label font color when selected in uitableview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom cell with imageview and label.When user selected a particular cell in the tableview I want change its image and the label font color.How can I do this ?I want to avoid that default way of cell selection(highlight cell in blue color) and use above method instead of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     MyCustomCell *selectedCell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     //selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = <#your color#>
     //selectedCell.myImage = <#your image>

}
```

if you want changed selected cell backgroundColor, try to this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *cellId = @"cellIdentifier";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
     if(!cell)
     {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];

        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I have done this.But When I select another cell,Then the first selected cell and the second selected cell both have the highlighted image.I want to avoid that.I want the default cell selection behavior.(When I select another cell after selecting a first cell,The first cell image should be the normal image and second cell image should be the highlighted image)How can I achieve this?

Comment: I got it done by using - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{//selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = <#your color#>
     //selectedCell.myImage = <#your image>

}Then I could get back the Normal image when cell deselected